# regex validation for age group

Tags: javascript

Am looking for a regex validator to validate age between 18 and 65 so far i have this:

```
^(1[90]|[2-6][0-9])$
```

Comment: why are you using regex for this? it's just a number, so you can use mathematical operator on it

Comment: `if (age >= 18 && age <= 65){}` , are you obligated to use regex?

Comment: Yes i could have done that but there is a reason why am using regex my code takes regex to do the validations so i don't want to implement any code for this i wanted to use regex

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to use regex for checking number ranges.

Below I've got a demo that checks the range the standard way, with greater than and less than but also I've included a regex way.

The regex way requires you to convert the number to a string first which is what the `toString()` bit is.

```js
const numbers = [1, 20, 55, 67];

for (let num of numbers) {
  if (num >= 18 && num <= 65)
    console.log(`standard: ${num} is in range`)
}

for (let num of numbers) {
  if (num.toString().match(/^([1][8-9]|[2-5][0-9]|[6][0-5])$/))
    console.log(`regex: ${num} is in range`)
}
```

Here is a diagram to explain how the regex works.
`^([1][8-9]|[2-5][0-9]|[6][0-5])$`
[image: Diagram]

Hope this is helpful.